# Error running Shell object / commands through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, shell, vba

I am running a C++ program through my VB code, and I am having trouble getting my code to run on a shared drive vs. on a local computer.  My program generates a set of assumptions, then runs those assumptions through a C++ model, then picks up the model output and prepares it for viewing in the VB workbook.

The code below works fine when I have the workbook saved in a local directory on my C drive, but when I upload it to my company's shared drive, I get the following error:

"Run-time error '-2147024894 (80070002)': Method 'Run' of object 'IWshShell3' failed"

Code:

```
'---------------------------------------------------------
' SECTION III - RUN THE MODEL AS C++ EXECUTABLE
'---------------------------------------------------------
Dim ModelDirectoryPath As String
Dim ModelExecutableName As String
Dim ModelFullString As String

' First build the command string
Application.StatusBar = "Running C++ Model..."

ModelDirectoryPath = Range("ModelFilePath").value
ModelExecutableName = Range("ModelFileName").value
ModelFullString = ModelDirectoryPath & ModelExecutableName
ModelFullString = ModelFullString & " " & ScenarioCounter & " " & NumDeals _
                  & " " & ModelRunTimeStamp & " " & Settle_YYMMDD

' Run the program
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
Dim errorCode As Integer

errorCode = wsh.Run(ModelFullString, windowStyle, waitOnReturn)

If errorCode = 0 Then
    ' MsgBox "C++ Model Completed without Errors."
Else
    MsgBox "Program exited with error code " & errorCode & "."
End If

Application.StatusBar = "C++ Model Complete"
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is a wild guess but... Comment out this line: `Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`. Replace `wsh.Run` with just `Shell`. What happens?

Comment: That works - that's actually what I am doing currently as a work-around.  The problem is that I need the program to provide feedback on when the model has completed running (so I can know when to run the output generation code)...

Comment: I noticed that my directory path on the "shared" version has a space in one of the folder names - could that be throwing things off?

Answer (score 18):

The error *does* come from the directory having a space in it:

```
C:\Users\myname\this is my folder\myexe.exe
```

A simple workaround does the trick:

```
wsh.Run(Chr(34) & YourFullPathDirectoryWithSpaces & "\myexe.exe" & Chr(34))
```

`Chr(34)` is a double quote.

There was an issue with `.Run` taking a two line property.

Tested it on Excel 2010/Win32.

Comment: My format got weird, there shouldn't be underscores before and after the Chr(34).

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, alternative solution:

```
wsh.CurrentDirectory = exePath
wsh.Run(exeName & " " & cmdArgs, windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
```

Key point being to set the CurrentDirectory property of the shell

Answer (score 0):

I have determined that the problem appears entirely due to the directory structure including a space.  There does not appear to be any issue relating to the local vs. shared directory.

If someone knows an easy fix to get around the directory having a space in it, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the problem only seems to occur when more than one argument is passed on to the program/script that is run.

If the second argument contains a filepath with a space, even when the necessary """" are present, the error occurs.

Can't find any solution at this point...

Answer (score 0):

found this [great reference](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/vba-shell) explaining triple quotes when there is a space in the path. Here is a portion of it in case it gets taken down or moves:

> if you had wanted to open a file
>
> `c:\My Files\Text File.txt` and your shell required that this be wrapped
>   in `""`, then you'd write the string like this
>
> `PID = Shell("notepad ""c:\My Files\Text File.txt""", vbNormalFocus)`
>
> The same goes for any path you need to specify for the actual
>   command/script name. In this example I'm calling a batch file (Text
>   Parser.bat) to process the text file (Text File.txt):
>
> `PID = Shell("""c:\My Scripts\Text Parser.bat"" ""c:\My Files\Text File.txt""", vbNormalFocus)`
>
> All of those `"""` look a bit strange but let me explain. The first and
>   last `"` mark the beginning and end of the string that specifies the
>   program being called, including any parameters, switches and file(s)
>   it will use:
>
> `"""c:\My Scripts\Text Parser.bat"" ""c:\My Files\Text File.txt"""` If
>   we remove those `"` we are left with the Program string itself, which is
>   composed of two separate strings, one for the path\batch file,
>   and the other for the path\file the batch file will use .
>
> `""c:\My Scripts\Text Parser.bat"" ""c:\My Files\Text File.txt""` When
>   this is passed to the Shell one of the double `"` is removed so what is
>   actually seen in the Shell is
>
> `"c:\My Scripts\Text Parser.bat" "c:\My Files\Text File.txt"` Which
>   looks like two normally delimited strings.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is ancient but I ran across the same issue and devised a solution.

Write some code to put that command into a batch file in C:\Temp... that way Shell or Wscript.Shell will receive a digestible "C:\Temp\thing.bat" as the argument.

Worked like a charm for me.  :)