# VBA excel : Using WScript to run bat file

Tags: windows, vba, excel

I am using the following VBA code to run a bat file. It was an example to run the note pad application instead of .bat file. 
While running  I am getting an error "Method run of object ISshShell3 failed"
Please let me know how can i use it to run the bat file from a desired directory?
My aim is to run a command on console  and wait for the command to finish.

```
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
Dim errorCode As Long
errorCode = wsh.Run("D:\test.bat", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
If errorCode = 0 Then
 MsgBox "Done! No error to report."
Else
  MsgBox "Program exited with error code " & errorCode & "."
End If
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your batch file code?  This VBA runs the following batch file code perfectly for me:
`net use`
`pause`

Comment: Here is [a similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267283/error-running-shell-object-commands-through-excel-vba) (is "IWshShell3" a mistype of "ISshShell3"? This is the only Google result for "ISshShell3").  If so, it looks like the error may be resolved by removing spaces from your directory (apparently not a problem with "D:\test.bat", or by setting `wsh.CurrentDirectory = exePath`... I can't test this because I still can't replicate the error, even when running a batch file from a flash drive or network folder... which makes me think your Windows or XL version may be relevant

Comment: Try `wsh.Run("cmd.exe /C D:\test.bat", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)`

Comment: thank you very much                                                                                                          I tried wsh.Run("cmd.exe /C D:\test.bat", windowStyle, waitOnReturn). It is working fine. Please let me know can we use the above command to run the command directly. For eg : D:\myfolder\make (without using a bat file). My aim is to run a command and wait till it finishes execution. And I want to know the exit status also.

Comment: @user3647205 probably not unless `D:\myfolder\make.exe` exists